# Sending Serial Data Between Two Virtual Machine in a Learning Practice

Tags: binary, serial-port, virtual-machine, port, qbasic

I am trying to send and receive data between two VM in Vm-Ware Workstation for learning purpose. I use Quick Basic IDE for progrmming serial COM Port.Operating system is Freedos in both VM's. Every VM uses a virtual port of windows host. The pair of virtual ports are made ELTIMA software.
I use two piece of basic code , one for sending and the other one for receiving as follow:

```
DIM bytestr AS STRING * 1

INPUT "COM port number #", port$
OPEN "COM" + port$ + ":9600,N,8,1,BIN,CS0,DS0" FOR RANDOM AS #1
CLS
DO
        k$ = INKEY$
        IF LEN(k$) = 1 THEN
                k = ASC(k$)
                IF k >= 32 THEN
                        PRINT ">" + k$ + "<";
                        bytestr = k$
                        PUT #1, , bytestr
                END IF
        END IF
LOOP UNTIL k$ = CHR$(27)
CLOSE #1: PRINT "Finished!"
```

and second peice for reciving :

```
CLS
DIM bytestr AS STRING * 1

INPUT "COM port number #", port$
OPEN "COM" + port$ + ":9600,N,8,1,ASC,CS0,DS0" FOR RANDOM AS #1
DO
        k$ = INKEY$
        IF LOC(1) THEN
                GET #1, , bytestr
                PRINT "[" + bytestr + "]";
        END IF
LOOP UNTIL k$ = CHR$(27)
CLOSE #1: PRINT "Finished!"
```

What I receive in receiving machine console are strange characters that are different from what was typed in sending machine. I cannot even find a logical relation between them.
Would you please explain me what is happening.

> Codes have borrowed from:
> https://www.qb64.org/wiki/OPEN_COM

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `OPEN "COM"` says:

> Currently, QB64 only supports OPEN FOR RANDOM access using the GET/PUT commands in **BIN** mode.

Your `OPEN` statement on the receiving end then erroneously uses `ASC` instead of `BIN`

> ```
> OPEN "COM" + port$ + ":9600,N,8,1,ASC,CS0,DS0" FOR RANDOM AS #1
>                                    ^
>                                    | Should be BIN
> ```

Comment: thank your kind answer .This Change does not resolve issue.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by replacing :        "GET #1, , bytestr"           with this one: 
    "bytestr=input$(loc(1),#1)"